# We have business hours that operates 11PM to 8AM but SF have validation Start time must be earlier than end time

Tags: businesshours

we have number sets of business hours of shifting of our agents.
Were wondering why Salesforce.com not allowing to set the end time earlier than the start time. We would like to use the standard business hours. Or were going to use custom setting and do a workaround approach?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is logical that a start time has to be prior to an end time in setting Business Hours.

To do what you are looking for I think you would need to set them up for a different time zone so that the hours actually did fit into the pattern of Start time before the end time. I presume that these agents are supporting remote clients not in your company's own time zone so you could select the appropriate time zone for the region that you are dealing with.